# Selecting only a specific key-value pair inside object

Tags: python, list, loops, object

I have this structure:

```
attributes_json = {
  "attributes": [
    {
      "color": "blue",
      "id": 78923,
      
    {
      "color": "red",
      "id": 321
```

I wanna select only the "color" key and its values and then put them inside a list, how can I do that in Python?

I have tried this so far but it only gives the first color:

```
lista = [item for item in attributes_json['attributes'][0]['color']]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: this: 
lista = [item for item in attributes_json['attributes'][0]['color']]

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the structure is a dictionary with a key "attributes", and "attributes" is a list of dictionaries, each with a key "color". You have the right idea, but you are only accessing the first entry. You need to loop over the list of dictionaries like so:

```
attributes_list = attributes_json["attributes"]

colors = []
for entry in attributes_list:
    color = entry["color"]
    colors.append(color)
```

In list comprehension form,

```
colors = [entry["color"] for entry in attributes_json["attributes"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

attributes =  attributes_json["attributes"]

color=[]
for x in attributes:
colors = x['color']
color.append('color')